# phpmyadmin - Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x81\x82' for column 'column1'

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I want to update table with japanese on phpmyadmin, but incorrect string value is thrown. Here's how I edit the table. I put the value 'あ' into nickname column and press 'GO'. Then, incorrect string value is thrown.

[image]

Here's the result I got. On nickname columns, '?' is shown.
[image]

Mysql version 5.5

Here's my database character set

```
character_set_client      | cp932
character_set_connection  | cp932
character_set_database    | cp932
character_set_filesystem  | binary
character_set_results     | cp932
character_set_server      | cp932
character_set_system      | utf8
```

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you are inserting this data and where it is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Update the column collation to cp932_japanese_ci instead of latin1_swedish_ci.

I was using the default collation. For japanese content, collation must be change to the suitable collation instead of using default collation.

Comment: that... or just use UTF-8 if you can.

Comment: I just tried out utf8_general_ci,utf8_spanish2_ci and utf8_swedish_ci. Its all works. Seem like utf8 collation is adaptable to japanese

Answer (score 0):

The byte sequence you mention is the UTF-8 representation of

```
あ
```

You seem to be inserting that multi-byte value into a single-byte encoding, where it of course is an invalid character.

Comment: Oh, so what should I do to make phpmyadmin to be able to insert multiple-byte value?

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about what you are doing. See the comment above

Comment: @edison in that case, it seems that phpMyAdmin has the wrong connection encoding. Strange, I don't think that should happen - it should convert the input automatically to the target charset. What does it say on the first page (I think) about its connection to the database? Can the character you show be used in the `cp932` encoding?